# How to maintain state after streaming application restart?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand how state management in Spark Streaming works in general. If I run this example program twice will the second run see state from the first run?
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala

Is there a way how to achieve this? I am thinking about redeploying an application an I would like not to loose the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** It depends on what you need the other instance to see. [Checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) is *usually* a solution.

`ssc.checkpoint(".")` (at [the line 50 in StatefulNetworkWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala#L50)) enables checkpointing that (quoting the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)):

> Spark Streaming needs to checkpoint enough information to a fault-tolerant storage system such that it can recover from failures.

A failure can be considered a form of redeployment. It is described in the official documentation under [Upgrading Application Code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#upgrading-application-code) that lists two cases:

- Two instances run in parallel
- One is gracefully brought down, and the other reads state from checkpoint directory.